# Can a minor travel to the UK with someone whose passport number does not appear on his visa?

Tags: visas, uk, shore-excursions

I am a teacher. I would like to take my students to the UK. Some of them already have a visa for the UK. My passport number does not appear on their visa. Is there any way for me to accompany them?

Comment: What type of visa do they have exactly? If it's a visa to accompany a parent then you likely cannot use it for a school trip.

Comment: Their visa is to accompany a parent

Answer (score 5):

**No**, not unless their visa is unaccompanied. If they have an Accompanied minor visa and you’re not listed on it you can not take them with you without the person(s) listed on that visa.

> **Travelling with an adult**
>
> When travelling to the UK with an adult (someone over the age of 18), you’ll need to identify them in your visa application.
>
> If the person you’re travelling with isn’t your parent, you’ll need to provide specific information about them in your application.
>
> Their name will appear on your visa, and you’ll be refused entry to the UK if you arrive in the UK without them.
>
> You can identify up to 2 adults in your visa application, and your visa will only be valid if you travel with at least one of them.

[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18)